# Get Latest posts from WordPress Site Xamarin Application

Tags: wordpress, xamarin, rss

Im currently trying to develop a simple Xamarin cross platform app which will display posts from a WordPress site.

I am currently getting data from the site by using the RSS feed and displaying it through a ListView.

However the feed is quite large and I just want to get the top 10 at most.
Is there a filter I can apply to the RSS feed to only take the latest feeds?

Possibly a plugin or library?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Wordpress --> Settings --> Reading

Syndication Feeds Show the Most Recent XX Elements
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jason